# Table with 6 columns with Jquery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, css-tables

Should I build a table with 6 columns, I can not do it, by the time I built 2 tables with 3 columns but I can not make them side by side, I am one below the other. How can I do?

The style:

```
<style>
  /*Set 3.colum grid*/
     .ui-grid-b .grid1{
     width=50%;
     align="left";
     }
     .ui-grid-b .grid2{
      width=50%
      align="rigth";
     }   
 </style>
```

The code:

```
  <div class="ui-grid-b" id="grid1">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">A</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">B</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">C</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">A</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">B</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">C</div></div>
        </div><!-- /grid-b  -->

        <div class="ui-grid-b" id="grid2">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">A</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">B</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">C</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">A</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">B</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:120px">C</div></div>
        </div><!-- /grid-b -->

 </div>
```

Comment: this looks better without inline styles http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gwCSL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two main girds `ui-grid-a`. Inside each, add two blocks `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b` and each should accommodate `ui-grid-b` and its children `ui-block-a`, `ui-block-b` and `ui-block-c`.

Also, use the below instead of inline styling

```
.ui-block-a  > div.ui-bar, .ui-block-b  > div.ui-bar, .ui-block-c > div.ui-bar {
  height: 120px !important
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gwCSL/)**